# Rails create scope of duplicates records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If you need to pull all duplicates by name in the class you can achieve it by:

```
Company.select(:name).group(:name).having("count(*) > 1")
```

By what to do if you want it in the scope

```
scope :duplicates, -> { where (...?)}
```

Also in return I need few fields not only name. Did anyone had the same problem to  create a scope?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run this in two queries. The first query selects the duplicate names, the second one selects the records with those duplicate names **and uses the `current_scope` so that it can be chained with more scopes** if needed (unfortunately `current_scope` seems to be a very useful but [undocumented](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping.rb#L13) method):

```
scope :duplicates,
      -> {
        dup_names = Company.group(:name).having("count(*) > 1").pluck(:name)             
        current_scope.where(name: dup_names)
      }
```

(The `dup_names` variable will contain an array of duplicate names found among the companies.)

Then you can easily add further conditions on the duplicate records, for example:

```
Company.duplicates.where("name like 'a%'").limit(2)
```

will select just two companies with the name starting with 'a' (and with duplicate names).

Comment: Thanks for reply. This might do the work if you looking for one field data in array. But if I need more then name field in array, then it is not happening,  probably because of previous grouping.  So something like this wouldn't work - Company.group(:name).having("count(*) > 1").pluck(:name, :id)

Comment: I think you might be misunderstanding how `group` works (or maybe I don't understand what you are trying to achieve). If you run just `Company.duplicates`, it will return all records with dup names with all their attributes, including `id`. That is what the second query in the scope does. It makes no sense to try to select (or `pluck`) `id` when you group by `name` as the grouping function will select a single (random) record for each group.

Answer (score 0):

Since

`scope :red, -> { where(color: 'red') }`

is simply 'syntactic sugar' for defining an actual class method:

```
class Shirt < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.red
    where(color: 'red')
  end
end
```

you could define scope like this:

`scope :duplicates, -> { ids = select(:id).group(:name).having("count(name) > 1"); where(id: ids) }`

Comment: Is the results not what you want or syntax error or...? could you provide some log or details.